# Report how much space is used and available in storage in ZFS on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, zfs, storage, bsd

When using [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) on [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD), how can we see how much space is used and how much is available in [storage drives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_data_storage) (hard disk, SSD, etc.)?

For example, spinning up a virtual machine instance of FreeBSD on [DigitalOcean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigitalOcean) comes with a certain amount of storage. How can I verify the size of that virtual drive?

Comment: Try: `zfs list`

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks. I made an Answer of your Comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## `zfs list`

Use the `list` option on the `zfs` command built into FreeBSD.

```bash
zfs list
```

Example:

```
$ zfs list
NAME                 USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
zroot               4.41G  17.4G    88K  none
zroot/ROOT          3.49G  17.4G    88K  none
zroot/ROOT/default  3.49G  17.4G  3.15G  legacy
zroot/tmp            112K  17.4G   112K  /tmp
zroot/usr            947M  17.4G    88K  /usr
zroot/usr/home       184K  17.4G   128K  /usr/home
zroot/usr/ports      947M  17.4G   947M  /usr/ports
zroot/usr/src         88K  17.4G    88K  /usr/src
zroot/var            792K  17.4G    88K  /var
zroot/var/audit       88K  17.4G    88K  /var/audit
zroot/var/crash       88K  17.4G    88K  /var/crash
zroot/var/log        348K  17.4G   348K  /var/log
zroot/var/mail        92K  17.4G    92K  /var/mail
zroot/var/tmp         88K  17.4G    88K  /var/tmp
$
```

Learn more on the [`zfs` man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=zfs&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html). The `zfs` command has many options for controlling the rich features of the [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) file system.

Answer (score 1):

For ZVOLs use this one:

```
# zfs get volsize
```